# Regex between two words - or to end of line?

Tags: regex

Simple regex question..

I have a very basic expression built to pull text out between two words:

```
BEGN:  (.*?)DETAIL:
```

Which works fine when both words exist, but on some occasions there is no "DETAIL:" so in those cases I just want to capture to the end of the text.  Is that possible with a single expression, or do I need a conditional statement of some type?

Comment: If my answer helped please consider accepting.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is to use a group with a `$` (end-of-string anchor) alternation:

```js
BEGN:  (.*?)(?:DETAIL:|$)
BEGN:  (.*?)(?=DETAIL:|$)
(?<=BEGN:  ).*?(?=DETAIL:|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w5IzsQ/1).

The `(?:DETAIL:|$)` is a non-capturing group that matches `DETAIL:` or end of string. The other two cases are similar, just the left- and right-hand delimiters are put into non-cosuming lookarounds so that the text they match could be omitted from the match value.

**There are alternative solutions.**

If the trailing delimiter can be absent, use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) or an unrolled one:

```
BEGN:  ((?:(?!DETAIL:).)*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF5kZ6/1)

The `(?:(?!DETAIL:).)*` matches any text up to the first `DETAIL:`. You may add a word boundary `\b` before `D` so as to only match `DETAIL` that is a whole word.

If the text can be spanning across multiple lines, do not forget a DOTALL modifier. If you use an unrolled version, the DOTALL modifier is not needed:

```
BEGN:  ([^D]*(?:D(?!ETAIL:)[^D]*)*)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF5kZ6/3)